# Regex_subtr in oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have hit the wall. I need to extract the from: Date and the To: Date from the text below.
It will always start with the date. But the changed from: and changed to: can sometimes be [none] instead of the date pattern.

Column:

```
"31-Jul-2017 11:29 (GMT+1:00) Date Due was modified by: placeholder, SNO-1234.

**Changed from: 12-Dec-2017**

**Changed to: 01-Jan-2021**

Meaning: Initial Entry 
Meaning Comments:"
```

Wanted output:

```
Column = From: "12-Dec-2017"       
Column = Changed To: "01-Jan-2021"
```

I have tried

```sql
cast(regexp_substr(column:, 'from:\s.*') as varchar(17)) as "From:",

cast(regexp_substr(column:, 'to:\s.*') as varchar(15)) as "Changed To:"
```

and i end up with..

```
Column = From: "**From:** 12-Dec-2017"                     
Column = Changed To: "**To:** 01-Jan-2021"
```

Anyway to exclude the from: and to: ? so basicly, how can i ONLY get the 11 characters after "from: " and "to: ".

Thanks in advance!

\GloriousWater

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression, you can use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN from_pos > 0
       THEN TO_DATE(
              SUBSTR( value, from_pos + 14, 11 )
              DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
              'DD-MON-YYYY'
            )
       END AS from_dt,
       CASE
       WHEN to_pos > 0
       THEN TO_DATE(
              SUBSTR( value, to_pos + 12, 11 )
              DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
              'DD-MON-YYYY'
            )
       END AS to_dt
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR( LOWER( value ), 'changed from: ', 1, 1 ) AS from_pos,
         INSTR( LOWER( value ), 'changed to: ', 1, 1 ) AS to_pos
  FROM   table_name
);
```

However, if you did want to use (slower) regular expressions then you could use:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           value,
           'changed from:\s*(([012]\d|3[01])-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-\d{4})',
           1,
           1,
           'i',
           1
         )
         DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
         'DD-MON-YYYY'
       ) AS from_dt,
       TO_DATE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           value,
           'changed to:\s*(([012]\d|3[01])-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-\d{4})',
           1,
           1,
           'i',
           1
         )
         DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
         'DD-MON-YYYY'
       ) AS to_dt
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '31-Jul-2017 11:29 (GMT+1:00) Date Due was modified by: placeholder, SNO-1234.
Changed from: 12-Dec-2017
Changed to: 01-Jan-2021
Meaning: Initial Entry Meaning Comments:' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> ```
> FROM_DT             | TO_DT              
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 2017-12-12T00:00:00 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab127ce1aa80e17d4d16564edfac7ecb)*

Comment: Thank you! 

I had some problems implementing the string function as it wouldn't recognize the from statement. i exchange "value" with the column containing the text to be parsed and table_name with the original from statement but it gives me some ) errors or wont recognize the columns. In the original from statement i have 1 table and 2 left joins.